# Can I bifurcate a tensorflow checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use Bert pretrained model for embedding generation. The checkpoint file is too big for my system and I am looking at ways to bifurcate the ckeckpoint.

I have renamed the tensor names to remove "/" and put "_" in their place using [this](https://gist.github.com/batzner/7c24802dd9c5e15870b4b56e22135c96). I have restored the model but am unable to save the new variables as it gives NameError: name 'bert_encoder_layer_9_intermediate_dense_kernel' is not defined

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("../bert/Renamedmodel.ckpt.meta")
saver.restore(sess, "../bert/Renamedmodel.ckpt")
varnames = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if "Variable" in n.op]
savesome = tf.train.Saver({"ker":bert_encoder_layer_9_intermediate_dense_kernel})
savesome.save(sess)
```

Is there a way to bifurcate and then join back the checkpoint file using the meta file to load the graph?